# How to change the colour and or decoration of the text on tapping the text

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have some numbers in `PageView`. On click of any number it should highlight(should change colour and decoration like show a circle around the selected text). This basically is a calendar. On click of any date it should highlight the selected date.

Here is my code:

```
 Widget _days(int week) {
var now = DateTime.now();
var currentDate = now.day;
var year = now.year;
var date = DateTime(year, index + 1).subtract(Duration(days: 1)).day;

return Center(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                String slectedMonth;
                if (index < 10) {
                  slectedMonth = '0$index';
                }
                String tapDate = (i + (week * 7)).toString();
                if (int.tryParse(tapDate) < 10) {
                  tapDate = '0$tapDate';
                }
                setState(() {
                  selectedDate = '$year-$slectedMonth-$tapDate';
                });
              },
              child: ((week * 7) + i) == currentDate
                  ? Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(9),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey),
                      child: Text(
                        ((week * 7) + i) < date
                            ? ((week * 7) + i).toString() + ""
                            : '',
                        style: TextStyle(),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Text(
                      ((week * 7) + i) < date
                          ? ((week * 7) + i).toString() + " "
                          : '',
                      style: TextStyle(),
                    )),
        ),
    ],
  ),
  );
 }
```

And I am calling the method as:

```
  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 50,
                    child: PageView(
                      controller: _pageController,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _days(0),
                        _days(1),
                        _days(2),
                        _days(3),
                        _days(4),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int index = 0;
  String selectedDate, tappedDate;
  PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 50,
          child: PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            children: <Widget>[
              _days(0),
              _days(1),
              _days(2),
              _days(3),
              _days(4),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget _days(int week) {
var now = DateTime.now();
var currentDate = now.day;
var year = now.year;
var date = DateTime(year, index + 1).subtract(Duration(days: 1)).day;

return Center(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
                  String slectedMonth;
                  if (index < 10) {
                    slectedMonth = '0$index';
                  }
                  tappedDate = (i + (week * 7)).toString();
                  if (int.tryParse(tappedDate) < 10) {
                    tappedDate = '0$tappedDate';
                  }
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDate = '$year-$slectedMonth-$tappedDate';
                  });
                },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: tappedDate == ((week * 7) + i).toString()
              || tappedDate == ('0'+((week * 7) + i).toString())
                ? Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(9),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.green),
                    child: Text(
                      ((week * 7) + i) < date
                          ? ((week * 7) + i).toString() + ""
                          : '',
                      style: TextStyle(),
                    ),
                  )
                : ((week * 7) + i) == currentDate
                    ? Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(9),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey),
                        child: Text(
                          ((week * 7) + i) < date
                              ? ((week * 7) + i).toString() + ""
                              : '',
                          style: TextStyle(),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(
                        ((week * 7) + i) < date
                            ? ((week * 7) + i).toString() + " "
                            : '',
                        style: TextStyle(),
                      ),
          ),
        ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Grey is Today !
Green is Selected !

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks Naveen. This is working fine but i cannot select date from 1 to 9

Answer (score 0):

Note that here I have created a package for this. https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_indicator. But there are no support for page dragging yet.

Anyway, Change your method like this, it will work:

```
  String day = "0";

  Widget _days(int week) {
    int index = week;
    var now = DateTime.now();
    var currentDate = now.day;
    var year = now.year;
    var date = DateTime(year, index + 1).subtract(Duration(days: 1)).day;

    return Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                  String slectedMonth;
                  if (index < 10) {
                    slectedMonth = '0$index';
                  }
                  String tapDate = (i + (week * 7)).toString();
                  setState(() {
                    day = tapDate;
                  });
                  if (int.tryParse(tapDate) < 10) {
                    tapDate = '0$tapDate';
                  }
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDate = '$year-$slectedMonth-$tapDate';
                  });
                },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: ("${((week * 7) + i)}" == day) ? Color(0xFF55555+i) : null,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: ((week * 7) + i) == currentDate
                      ? Container(
                    child: Text(
                      ((week * 7) + i) < date
                          ? ((week * 7) + i).toString() + ""
                          : '',
                      style: TextStyle(),
                    ),
                  )
                      : Text(
                    ((week * 7) + i) < date
                        ? ((week * 7) + i).toString() + " "
                        : '',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: @USER9561 Yeah sorry my bad, It was because the condition, I change it if you interested